# Artificial intelligence used for recognizing emojis on wallpaper

Tags: image-recognition, google-vision, google-cloud-automl, automl

I want to build an app that will recognize what emojis have been used on the wallpaper.

So for instance this app will receive on input:

[image]

And on output should array of names of recognizing emojis return:

```
[
  "Smiling Face with Sunglasses", 
  "Grinning Face with Smiling Eyes", 
  "Kissing Face with Closed Eyes"
]
```

I have prepared training data that consists of individual emojis.
For instance, I have rotated each emoji by 30 degrees, cut it by half, etc.

After training the model, the average precision is `0.8`, which is quite nice, but it only works for one emoji per wallpaper. If I upload many types of emojis on one wallpaper, it does not recognize any objects.

My question is: why does it recognize one type of emoji per wallpaper, but if I put many types of emojis on one wallpaper, it does not work?

I am using Google ML Vision, and I have chosen `Multi-Label Classification` for the data set.

Comment: Could you share the sample dataset along with your training code as a reproducible sample?

Comment: I do not have a sample code, everything was done by UI on Google console. 
How big dataset do you need?

Comment: As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/prepare#preparing_your_images), AutoML Vision recommends about 1000 training images per label. The minimum per label is 10, or 50 for advanced models. In general, it takes more examples per label to train models with multiple labels per image, and resulting scores are harder to interpret. So, make sure you have followed all recommended best practices to prepare your training data.

Comment: I have followed, I have prepared around 100 images per each label.

Comment: I would recommend you to try using object detection for your requirement. An object detection model analyzes your image data and returns annotations for all objects found in an image, consisting of a label and bounding box location for each object. So provide unannotated images in your .csv import file and use the UI to provide image annotations (bounding box and the label). Train a new model and pass many types of emojis on a single image to the detection, which would return the emoji name for each emoji in the different bounding boxes.

Comment: Refer to these docs for more information about [preparing your training data](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/prepare) and [annotating images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/label#annotating_images_via_the_web_ui).

Answer (score -1):

Object detection involves identifying and locating various objects in images or video frames, while vehicle number plate detection specifically targets recognizing license plates on vehicles. Both tasks rely on similar principles of image processing but have distinct focuses and challenges. Understanding one can offer insights into the other, but they require different approaches due to the nature of the objects being detected.

Comment: Chandni, your answer makes sense, but is written in a way that is hard to understand. Please review it. Maybe you should ask some help from someone who can write good English.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).